# How to make Perl script executable?

Tags: perl, permissions, executable

I have given a perl script file executable permission on a Unix based system, but when I try to execute the file I get a `"command not found"` error. I have `#!usr/local/bin/perl` at the start of the script file.

Comment: `#!/usr/...` - note the third character.

Comment: @Amadan Why does the filename only tab-complete when I starting typing `./<filename>` and not when I just starting the filename?

Comment: Because your current directory is not in your `$PATH`. If it's in your `$PATH`, you can execute simply by typing the name; if it is not, you need to specify the location.

Comment: @Amadan It doesn't make sense. Why is it like that?

Comment: It only doesn't make sense if you are used to Windows and DOS. It is like that because of security reasons (e.g. you want to run `perl`, but someone puts a file named `perl` in current directory that deletes all your files - you don't want to be executing that).

Comment: Actually, `#!usr/local/bin/perl` will (probably) work OK provided you have a program called `perl` in the directory `./usr/local/bin` (a sub-directory of your current directory).  It's just that most people don't keep Perl there — they keep it in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.  Of course, if your current directory was the root directory, `/`, then the script would probably work. (I demoed it working OK on Mac OS X with: `mkdir -p usr/bin; cp $(which cat) usr/bin/perl; echo '#!usr/bin/perl -' > ./ssss; echo 'This is not a Perl script' >> ./ssss; chmod +x ./ssss; ./ssss` — and typed some data.)

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your script, replace the `#!usr/local/bin/perl` with `#!/usr/bin/perl` notice the root '/' prior to the usr/

And you can try `perl <filename>` keyword to run the file instead of `./<filename>`, using perl keyword should run the script regardless of the shebang line at the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

replace your first line `#!usr/local/bin/perl` with `#!usr/bin/perl`(which is called Shebang). Then you can run the file with `perl <Path To File>`.